# Is my iMac crashing because of a faulty HD that I'm not using anymore?

Tags: hard-drive, imac, crash

I have an iMac (Retina 5K, 27-inch, late 2014). A while back the fusion drive died and I split them and used the SSD for the OS and an external 2TB SSD for storage.
The only issue I have had with the computer from this until now, is that it did not want to go to sleep. It also sounded like the HD kept spinning.

As of today the iMac keeps crashing and rebooting. When it's back up it warns that it can't read a connected drive.

Diskutil overview: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nR44c.jpg

I believe ST3000DM001 is the culprit. I can't dismount nor format it.

Crash log: https://gist.github.com/sxaman/39a3edf7b8597460fbb278570d473e2e

Is it reasonable to think the old HDD is making my iMac crash?
If so, would a working fix be to remove power and data cable from the HDD? (I hope that is possible without interfering with the internal SSD.)
Or is there a less intrusive way (without having to take the iMac apart), where I can disable the old HDD completely?

Any help or suggestions are very much appreciated.

Comment: Boot in Recovery mode and perhaps you can repair or erase the HDD. Just be careful not to erase the SSD.

Comment: I would advise you to do some more testing: Try the different startup modes, especially `D`, NVRAM reset and safe mode (https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201255). Also, if you can, try installing macOS on an external drive and see if it problems persist. If yes, it's a hardware issue. Also try disk repair in disk utility for your drives (several times! and maybe even in recovery mode). In general though, a non-mountable drive should not interfere with the system.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions.
I did the NVRAM reset. Also the Apple Diagnostics (D) which found no errors.
First Aid in disk utility (both booted and during recovery, found no errors). Running it on the HDD just completes instantly with no errors or information what so ever.
While testing it out, the computer has crashed and rebooted several times within Recovery mode. Same thing happens when the external SSD is disconnected. It has to be a hardware issue then right?

Comment: I also have tried to install macOS on another external drive. Computer crashed and rebooted before it was done.

Comment: Yes. Everything points to hardware fault.

Comment: Exactly the same problem here, unfortunately (iMac late 2012); see also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ST3000DM001

Answer (score 1):

I finally build up the courage to try and disconnect the faulty HD. I was sorta successful.
The screen cracked a bit and my iMac is now assembled again with duct tape. But it seems to work. There was no error when starting the iMac, and it has been running now for 30 mins without issues. I will update this if that changes, but I'm having my hopes up.